# Collecting keyboard shortcuts for menu items of another application

Tags: macos, menu, accessibility, nsmenuitem

I'm writing an application that allows access to other applications' menu items via the accessibility framework. I have no problem obtaining the list of menus, their menu items, etc..

As far as I can see, however, the accessibility framework does not give access to the keyboard shortcuts for each item.

More concretely, if my app presents the `Finder`'s `File` -> `New Finder Window` menu item, I would like to annotate it on screen with `Command-N`, so the user can learn the shortcuts by heart.

At the moment I see no way of getting that information. If not via the `AXUIElement` accessibility framework, how else can one get that info?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which attributes do you use, do they have "menuitem" siblings? Have you tried `AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames`?

Comment: Could you please share how you read "obtaining the list of menus, their menu items, etc"? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find `AXMenuItemCmdChar` and associated `AXUIElement` attributes that actually have the information I'm after. Unfortunately, the Swift framework that I use to bridge the C-level Carbon accessibility APIs defines a convenient enum for all the attributes.. only it's not quite **all** the attributes :-(